# problems with calling method of ViewController before calling viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have two view controllers in Xcode project (all view controllers are created in storyboard).

First view controller has two (or more) buttons with certain background images. Second view controller should display full-screen background image of certain button after user touch it (certain button).

Second view controller has a property `UIImageView` that should be allocated and initialized in the code of second view controller (`UIImageView` not created in storyboard).

Second view controller is a delegate for first view controller and has a method:

```
-(void) viewController:(ViewController *) viewController buttonPressed: (UIButton *) button.
```

Every button has a modal segue to second view controller.

So the sequence of actions of application is next (I realized that by debugging):

1. User touches any button
2. Button calls an action method in which delegate method `viewController:buttonpressed:` is called. `UIImageView` instance is allocated and initialized in this method with the image returned by `button backgroundImageForState:`
3. Than method `viewDidLoad` of second view controller is called, in which `UIImageView` instance should be added to super view of second view controller and displayed on screen.

**The problem** is that despite of allocation of `UIImageView` instance in delegate method `viewController:buttonpressed:`, that instance is become `nil` at the start of method `viewDidLoad` of second view controller. All actions that been made in `viewController:buttonpressed:` became unavailing.

The code is below:

First View Controller Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ViewControllerForImage *temp = (ViewControllerForImage *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControlForImage"];

    self.delegate = temp;
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    [self.delegate viewController:self buttonPressed:sender];
}
```

Second View Controller Code

```
@synthesize myImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:myImage];
}    

-(void) viewController:(ViewController *) viewController buttonPressed: (UIButton *) button{
    myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[button backgroundImageForState: UIControlStateNormal]];

    [myImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 504)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just pass the information in a prepareForSegueMethod?

Also in your code why are you sending an instance of viewcontroller back to the second view controller? You are not using it at all.

Comment: Thanks! It helps me! I've just used prepareForSeque method to allocate and initialize UIImageView of second view controller!